# Meaning of "#include <path/to/header>" directive (like "#include <loki/Functor.h>")

Tags: c++

I am trying to use code (mostly header files) from the [Loki library](https://github.com/snaewe/loki-lib) to test it's functionalities. I am getting error for lines that have `#include <loki/Typelist.h>` directives. I have never seen a path inside the < > or such. (I know about the normal `#include <strings>` etc directives, and that it searches predefined path)

How does the include directives of the form `<path/to/header>` work?

Am I right to assume that the library inserts itself into one of the standard paths that the compiler searches in? If so, any way to use it without inserting the library into said path. (I just want to test a function that includes these headers)

**EDIT:**

**Test.cpp**

```
#include "Functor.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct TestFunctor
{
    void operator()(int i, double d)
    {
        cout << " TestFunctor called.\n";
    }
};

int main()
{
    TestFunctor f;
    Functor<void, TYPELIST_2(int, double)> cmd(f);
    cmd(4, 4.5);
}
```

**Note:** The Test.cpp file rests in loki-lib/include/loki

**Error:**

```
$ gcc Test.cpp
In file included from Test.cpp:1:0:
Functor.h:34:10: fatal error: loki/Typelist.h: No such file or directory
 #include <loki/Typelist.h>
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

Comment: From a glance, it looks like there's a [`loki/Typelist.h`](https://github.com/snaewe/loki-lib/blob/7c29d87ecdecd60e39db969125753f6a4f549131/include/loki/Typelist.h) file. Are you sure that's not what you're looking for? (as opposed to `loki/Typelists` like you have written)

Comment: @scohe001 Thanks, fixed it. Also added link to Loki Library.

Comment: [mcve], command line, etc? I suspect that you are including files strangely.

Comment: @User10482 you misunderstand. I'm talking about how you have a plural Typelist***s*** as opposed to the singular that lives in that repo.

Comment: @scohe001 Oh, I see. That was just a made up directive to explain question. I have attached my Test.cpp code.

Comment: All questions on stackoverflow.com must include all pertinent information ***in the question itself as plain text***. Suspicious links to shady external web sites, that can stop working at any time and render the question meaningless, are not acceptable.

Comment: I am with Marc Glisse, please provide a [mcve] directly here, as text.

Comment: @Sam Varshavchik I will edit it.  Funny enough, someone on stackoverflow suggested me to use it to share code.

Comment: Sorry to hear that. Not all recommendations are good. Not even those of multi-digit-reputation users.... (making fun of myself, yes; but otherwise serious)

Comment: Please also provide more details on what error you get (quote completely, verbatim and as text) and on how you build (build commandline, makefile, GUI config).

Comment: I don't see the relation between the code you link to (where there is no file Function.h, of course) and the question. There is a search path, composed for instance of path1 and path2 (you can add to it with -I), and `#include <X>` looks for path1/X or path2/X. If X is a/b, that means it looks for path1/a/b or path2/a/b. It is weird to put your Test.cpp file in include/loki, and it doesn't mean you can skip adding -I/some/path.

Comment: @MarcGlisse #include "Functor.h" directive works as expected, since the Test.cpp is in the same folder as it. The error occurs after the pre-processor for the #include <loki/Typelist.h> line inside Functor.h. It fails to find it. I understand what you mean. I was trying to use the header files directly without utilizing the makefile (which I am guessing would copy/link "loki/all_header_files" to the default search path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Meaning of "`#include <path/to/header>`" directive (like "`#include <loki/Functor.h>`")

The c++ standard (latest draft) says:

> A preprocessing directive of the form
>
> ```
> # include < h-char-sequence > new-line
> ```
>
> searches a sequence of implementation-defined places for a header identified uniquely by the specified sequence between the < and > delimiters, and causes the replacement of that directive by the entire contents of the header.
>   How the places are specified or the header identified is implementation-defined.

---

Implementation defined behaviour depends on the implementation of the language that you are using. Example documentation for the GCC compiler:

> ```
> #include <file>
> ```
>
> This variant is used for system header files. It searches for a file named file in a standard list of system directories. You can prepend directories to this list with the -I option (see Invocation).

According to the [Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_3.0/fhs-3.0.html#usrincludeDirectoryForStandardInclu), the standard location should be `/usr/include` on Linux systems for example.

`-v` option of the GCC compiler should reveal the exact list of system include directories used by the compiler.

---

> Am I right to assume that the library inserts itself into one of the standard paths that the compiler searches in?

The compiler searches for the standard directories, yes. If the headers aren't in searched directories, then they will not be found.

> If so, any way to use it without inserting the library into said path.

As per the quoted documentation, you can use the `-I` (capital i) option to add a non standard include location, if you use GCC.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The last point solved the issue. I added the path myself instead depending on the makefile, and going through the make process.

Answer (score 1):

Though it's technically implementation-defined, in practice, most systems (Windows and Linux) use slashes (forward or backward) to specify paths (directories), as I'm sure you're aware. Some compilers, I believe GCC included, automatically convert paths specified in #include directives to the correct directory separator for the system on which they are running. The path in the specific example you list, `loki/Typelist.h`, is a relative path. So the compiler will look, beginning in all of the directories in its #include file search path, for a file whose relative path, beginning in any of those directories, matches `loki/Typelist.h`.

BTW you can add paths to the #include search path by adding `-I` options to your compiler command line; e.g. `-IC:\OpenSSL-Win32\include`. If you use a makefile, you might be able to add these by appending to the `COPTS` (or similar) variable.